# How can we prove that $[ {c^n - (a^n+b^n)} + d^n ] / (ab-cd)$ will yield integers always?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let us say $a<b<c$ and $(a+b)=(c+d)$ as well as $n\geq2$. Then it is found for all values of $n$ that 
>   $$
>   \frac{{c^n-(a^n+b^n)}+d^n}{ab-cd} \in \mathbb{Z}
> $$

Can you explain the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried to explain/prove it yourself? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have worked out and found that (ab-cd) is gcd of LHS & RHS

Comment: For aesthetical reasons, the fraction should be written as $\dfrac{(c^n+d^n)-(a^n+b^n)}{ab-cd}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch of a symmetrical functions proof:** let's denote $s=a+b=c+d$, $p=ab$, $q=cd$.

By Newton'identities, we know $a^n+b^n$ is a polynomial $P_n(s,p)\in \mathbf Z[s,p]$ and $c^n+d^n=P_n(s,q)$.

What we have to show is $P_n(s,p)-P_n(s,q)$  is divisible by $p-q$. This results from *Taylor's formula* for polynomials.

*Details:* Indeed, we know Taylor's  formula is an exact formula for polynomials. Let's consider $P_n(s,p)$ and $P_n(s,q)$ as the evaluation of a polynomial $P_n(s,x)$ at $p$ and $q$ respectively. If $d$ is its degree, Taylor's formula  can be written as:
$$P_n(s,p)-P_n(s,q)=(p-q)P'_n(s,q)+(p-q)^2\frac{P''_n(s,q)}{2}+\dots+(p-q)^d\frac{P^{(d)}_n(s,q)}{d\,!}$$
This proves $P_n(s,p)-P_n(s,q)$ is divisible by $p-q$, since all polynomials $\,\dfrac{P_n^{(k)}(s,x)}{k\,!}$ lis in $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proof by induction:

For $n=0$ or $n=1$, we have that
$$\frac{c^n-(a^n+b^n)+d^n}{ab-cd}=0 \in\mathbb{Z}$$
Now suppose that for some $n\geq 2$, we have that
$$\frac{c^k-(a^k+b^k)+d^k}{ab-cd}$$
is an integer for all $k < n$. We will show that then
$$\frac{c^n-(a^n+b^n)+d^n}{ab-cd}$$
is also an integer.

The Binomial Theorem gives us that
$$(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a^kb^{n-k}$$
and
$$(c+d)^n=c^n+d^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} c^kd^{n-k}$$
so that
$$c^n-(a^n-b^n)+d^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\left(c^kd^{n-k}-a^kb^{n-k}\right)$$
We want to show that this expression is congruent to $0$ modulo $ab-cd$.

Now
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\left(c^kd^{n-k}-a^kb^{n-k}\right) \equiv \sum_{0<2k<n}\binom{n}{k}\left(c^kd^{n-k}+c^{n-k}d^k-a^kb^{n-k}-a^{n-k}b^k\right) \mod (ab-cd)$$

(The sum ranging only over $2k<n$ is still valid when $n$ is even, since if $n=2k$, then
$$c^kd^{n-k}-a^kb^{n-k}\equiv (ab)^k-(ab)^k\equiv 0 \mod (ab-cd)$$
and so we can exclude the $2k=n$ term)

But
$$\sum_{0<2k<n}\binom{n}{k}\left(c^kd^{n-k}+c^{n-k}d^k-a^kb^{n-k}-a^{n-k}b^k\right)=\sum_{0<2k<n}\binom{n}{k}\left(c^kd^k(c^{n-2k}+d^{n-2k})-a^kb^k(a^{n-2k}+b^{n-2k})\right)
\equiv \sum_{0<2k<n}\binom{n}{k}\left(a^kb^k((c^{n-2k}+d^{n-2k})-(a^{n-2k}+b^{n-2k}))\right) \mod (ab-cd)$$

Now by the inductive hypothesis,
$$(c^{n-2k}+d^{n-2k})-(a^{n-2k}+b^{n-2k})\equiv 0\mod (ab-cd)$$
for each $0<2k<n$, and so
$$\sum_{0<2k<n}\binom{n}{k}\left(a^kb^k((c^{n-2k}+d^{n-2k})-(a^{n-2k}+b^{n-2k}))\right) \equiv 0\mod (ab-cd)$$
and so
$$c^n-(a^n+b^n)+d^n\equiv 0 \mod (ab-cd)$$
i.e.
$$\frac{c^n-(a^n+b^n)+d^n}{ab-cd}\in\mathbb{Z}$$
for $n$ as well.

Thus, by the principle of mathematical induction, we have that
$$\frac{c^n-(a^n+b^n)+d^n}{ab-cd}\in\mathbb{Z}$$
for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: I don't believe your base case works for $n=1$. Let $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=3$, $d=4$ then we have $$\frac{3-(1+2)+4}{1\cdot 2 - 3 \cdot 4} = \frac{4}{-10} \neq 0.$$

Comment: We use the condition that $a+b=c+d$

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $d=a+b-c$. Consider the polynomial :

$$
P(a,b,X)=X^n-(a^n+b^n)+(a+b-X)^n
$$

This is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $X$ (or degree $n-1$ if $n$ is odd), and we have
$P(a)=P(b)=0$. Since $a\neq b$, we deduce that $(X-a)(X-b)$
divides $P$ in ${\mathbb Z}[a,b,X]$ : there is a polynomial
$Q\in{\mathbb Z}[a,b,X]$ such that $P(a,b,X)=(X-a)(X-b)Q(a,b,X)$.

Then $\frac{c^n-(a^n+b^n)+d^n}{ab-cd}=Q(a,b,c)\in {\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: I don't see how you obtain $ab-cd$  as a denominator. Less important: if $n$ is odd, $P(a,b,X)$ will have degree $n-1$.

Comment: @Bernard 1) use $d=a+b-c$ to deduce $ab-cd=(c-a)(c-b)$. 2) Corrected, thanks.

Comment: I see. I also tried to use it it in several ways, but couldn't have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First we give a simple inductive proof then we give a *conceptual* interpretation of the induction as a special case of the uniqueness theorem for recurrences (difference equations).

**Hint** $\ $ The inductive step of a simple inductive proof follows by subtracting these

$$\begin{align}  
c^{n+2}+d^{n+2} &= (c+d)(c^{n+1}+d^{n+1}) - cd(c^n+d^n)\\
a^{n+2}+b^{n+2} &= (a+b)(a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}) - ab(a^n+b^n)\end{align}\qquad$$

Indeed $\,{\rm mod}\ ab\!-\!cd\!:\ $ by induction $\,c^k\!+d^k\equiv a^k\!+b^k\,$ for $\,k = n,\,n\!+\!1\,$ so subtracting

$$c^{n+2}\!+\!d^{n+2}\!-\!a^{n+2}\!-\!b^{n+2}\equiv \underbrace{(c\!+\!d\!-\!a\!-\!b)}_{\large =\, 0}(a^{n+1}\!+b^{n+1}) + \underbrace{(ab\!-\!cd)}_{\large \equiv\, 0}(a^n\!+b^n)\,\equiv\, 0$$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally this yields $\ \gcd(c\!+\!d\!-\!a\!-\!b,ab\!-\!cd)\mid c^n\!+d^n\!-a^n\!-b^n$

**Conceptually** $\ f_n = a^n\!+b^n$ and $\,{\bar f}_{\!n} =  c^n+d^n$ are both solutions of the same recurrence $\,  f_{n+2} = A f_{n+1} - B f_n\,$ for $\, a+b\equiv A\equiv c+d,\ $ $\,ab \equiv B\equiv cd,\,$ with same initial conditions $\,f_0 \equiv 2,\ f_1 \equiv a+b\equiv c+d,\,$ thus $\,f_n\equiv {\bar f}_{\!n}\,$ for all $\,n\,$ by the same simple induction as above. This is just  the *uniqueness theorem* for recurrences.

Answer (score 1):

High-school math proof:

We need to make use of the given condition. Let $u=a+b=c+d$, $v=a-b$ and $w=c-d$. Rewrite $a=(u+v)/2$, $b=(u-v)/2$, $c=(u+w)/2$ and $d=(u-w)/2$.

The denominator is then

$$ab-cd=\frac14\left(u^2-v^2-(u^2-w^2)\right)=\frac14\left(w^2-v^2\right)$$

The numerator is

$$\frac{1}{4^n}\left((u+w)^n+(u-w)^n-((u+v)^n+(u-v)^n)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4^n}\left(2\sum_{k=0,2,4\ldots}^n {n \choose k} u^{n-k} w^k -2\sum_{k=0,2,4\ldots}^n {n \choose k} u^{n-k} v^k \right)$$
$$=\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0,2,4\ldots}^n {n \choose k} u^{n-k} (w^k-v^k) $$

Because $k=2m$ is even, you just need to show that $w^2-v^2$ divides $(w^2)^m-(v^2)^m$, which is solved by a high-school level equality $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+\cdots)$.